# Count the occurrences of a string in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a file as below.

```
A      ctrl/bng/h2ert/scratch/TestAccountService.java
A      ctrl/bng/h2ert/scratch/TestAccount.java
A      ctrl/bng/h2ert/scratch/TestT.java
A      ctrl/bng/h2ert/scratch/TestAccountService.jpg
A      ctrl/bng/h2ert/scratch/TestService.txt
A      ctrl/bng/h2ert/scratch/TestAccountService.txt
```

I want to list all `.java` files names from the above, like

```
Total java file 4
```

then file name

Comment: When you say _then file name_, do you mean the name of the file that contains that list, or the names of the java files in that list?

Answer (score 7):

```
$ grep -c '\.java$' file
3
```

The `-c` flag to `grep` will make it report the number of lines in the input that matches the pattern.

The pattern `\.java$` will match any line that ends with `.java`.

```
$ name="file"
$ printf 'Total number of Java files in "%s":\t%d\n' "$name" "$( grep -c -- '\.java$' "$name" )"
Total number of Java files in "file":   3
```

Or even just (with GNU `grep` or compatible):

```
$ grep -Hc '\.java$' file
file:3
```

Or (still with GNU `grep`):

```
$ grep --label='Total java files in "file"' -Hc '\.java$' < file
Total java files in "file":3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, the all time classic awk:

```
awk '/\.java$/{++c}END{print "Total java files:" c}' file
```

If you want to print also those filenames you can change `{++c}` to `{print;++c}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '$a += s/\.java$//}{print"Total java file $ARGV: ", $a||0' java_file
```

The `s///` command returns the number of substitutions which is accumulated in `$a` and the result is printed at the end. The `$a||0` expression is used in the event there are no .java to be find at the end of lines.

```
perl -lne '$a += /\.java$/}{print"Total java file $ARGV: ", $a||0' java_file
```

This time we do a nondestructive test to determine the presence of .java. Rest of the details are the same.